How to show metadata navigation tree?
I have a SharePoint Team site.
I'm reading this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-up-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-c222a75d-8b18-44e2-9ed8-7ee4e0d23cfc?ui=en-us&rs=en-in&ad=in to setup metadata navigation.
Under site features, managed metadata navigation and filtering is ACTIVATED.
On a document library I have a choice column.
In the document library settings, under Metadata navigation settings, I have added a Choice column in the selected hierarchy fields section.
However, when I go to my document library I cannot see the metadata navigation.
If I switch to classic SharePoint experience then the metadata navigation shows up.
Is the metadata navigation not supported in the new SharePoint experience?
In the new experience site settings, under Navigation Elements I tried to turn on Enable Tree View. Once enabled, when I go to the document library I still cannot see the metadata navigation.
I don't want to use the classic SharePoint experience. What can I do to make use of metadata navigation in new sharpeoint experience?
